# Bash script: Save into mysql database

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I have to save a variable of my bash script into my mysql database.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `mysql` command, something like:

```
mysql -e "INSERT INTO tablename (colname) VALUES ('$variable')"
```